# Find the file name using python

Tags: python, string, pandas, filenames

I have a file with the following format in filename.txt file.

```
h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8db

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8dc

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8dx

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8du

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8d4

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8d5

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8d6

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8d7

h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8d8
```

I was able to read it well but unable to store in pandas data frame or the list or dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd

#data = pd.read_excel ('/home/home/Documents/pythontestfiles/HON-Lib.xlsx')
data = pd.read_table('/home/home/Documents/pythontestfiles/filename.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('A'))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['A'])
print(df)
```

and would like to list out the filename only as

```
hhhhhhhhhh8db

.

.

.

hhhhhhhhhh8d6

hhhhhhhhhh8d7

hhhhhhhhhh8d8
```

the purpose of storing in any data frame or dictionary is to compare against the excel file result.

Comment: Look for `split()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `split()`:

```
res = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
      content = file.readlines()
      for line in content:
            # print(line.split('\\')[-1])    # to print each name
            res.append(line.split('\\')[-1]) # append the name to the list
print(res)
```

**EDIT**:

Elaborating on the answer given, the `split()` method being applied on the string splits it by the `\\`, Consider the following example:

```
s = 'h:\abc\abc_Foldhr_1\hhhhhhhhhh8db'

print(s.split('\\'))
```

Which gives the output:

```
['h:\x07bc\x07bc_Foldhr_1', 'hhhhhhhhhh8db']
```

The `[-1]` index grabs the last element in it, hence:

```
print(s.split('\\')[-1])
```

Would give:

```
hhhhhhhhhh8db
```

Comment: i am not sure with -1 usage. Please share more thought.

Comment: @user3256224 the split() function basically splits the string by \\  and create a list of it.  `[-1]` grabs the last element in the list, i.e. `hhhhhhhhhh8db`

Comment: @user3256224 added an edit with the explanation as well.